# Java 8 : getting default values for a collection with nested Optionals

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, option-type

From [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html), there's a way to get the value of a nested [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) or a default value:

```
Optional<Computer> maybeComputer = Optional.of(computer);
String version = maybeComputer.flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard).flatMap(Soundcard::getUsb).map(USB::getVersion).orElse("UNKNOWN");
```

or

```
Computer computer = ...;
String version = computer.getSoundcard().flatMap(Soundcard::getUsb).map(USB::getVersion).orElse("UNKNOWN");
```

**BUT, how do I get all the versions of all collection's computers?** - `List<Computer>`

For example, how can I print all the USB versions, using `stream` API, **including the ones that are `unknown`**?

or

How can I map all the computers to their soundcard's USB version, including the `unknown` ones?

Thanks.

Computer class:

```
public static class Computer {
    private Optional<Soundcard> soundcard;

    public Computer(Optional<Soundcard> soundcard) {
        this.soundcard = soundcard;
    }

    public Optional<Soundcard> getSoundcard() {
        return soundcard;
    }
}

public static class Soundcard {
    private Optional<USB> usb;

    public Soundcard(Optional<USB> usb) {
        this.usb = usb;
    }

    public Optional<USB> getUsb() {
        return usb;
    }
}

public static class USB {
    private String version;

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no Optional in `List<Computer>`. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Tunaki - added `Computer` class definition.

Answer (score 4):

Just stream the list of computers and apply to each one of them the same mapping you apply to a single `Optional<Computer>`:

```
List<String> versions =
    computers.stream()
             .map(c -> Optional.ofNullable(c) // takes care of null elements in your List
                               .flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard)
                               .flatMap(Soundcard::getUsb)
                               .map(USB::getVersion)
                               .orElse("UNKNOWN"))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: For readability purposes, I'd recommend moving that lambda into a method in its own right.

Comment: @eran, Can there be a solution for handling the sub-value in the main pipeline? The current solution handles the sub-value, disconnected from the main pipeline. You created a sub-pipeline.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka There is just one Stream pipeline in this code. The lambda expression passed to the map method is not a Stream pipeline. It only operates on a single element of the Stream, and therefore cannot be combined into the Stream pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform the steps with the Stream API rather than the Optional API, you can use

```
computers.stream()
         .filter(Objects::nonNull)
         // Java 9: .flatMap(c -> c.getSoundcard().stream())
         .flatMap(c -> c.getSoundcard().map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
         // Java 9: .flatMap(s -> s.getUSB().stream())
         .flatMap(s -> s.getUsb().map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
         .map(USB::getVersion)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which differs in that it will skip absent values rather than substituting them with a default value ala `"UNKNOWN"`. It’s questionable anyway to produce a fall-back value `"UNKNOWN"` for the property “Soundcard’s USB version”, which could actually mean either “Not a USB device” or “No soundcard present”…

If you want to keep the original logic, you would have to carry the `Optional`s through the stream pipline, so that the information about presence or absence is retained:

```
computers.stream()
         .map(Optional::ofNullable)
         .map(oc -> oc.flatMap(Computer::getSoundcard))
         .map(os -> os.flatMap(Soundcard::getUsb))
         .map(os -> os.map(USB::getVersion))
         .map(ou -> ou.orElse("UNKNOWN"))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which is just a decomposed version of [Eran’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39685172/2711488). Note that this is not necessarily simpler than just using `null`:

```
computers.stream()
         .map(c -> c==null? null: c.getSoundcard().orElse(null))
         .map(s -> s==null? null: s.getUsb().orElse(null))
         .map(u -> u==null? "UNKNOWN": u.getVersion())
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```